# How can I get the image id after I click on it?

Tags: php, mysql, file, mysqli, upload

I'm in the middle of a project. I have stored images to be thumbnails for a corresponding video. I wan't to display the video that the thumbnail is for after I click on the image. However, when the user is brought to the next page, I recieve an error,

> **Notice**: Undefined index: v_id

v_id does exist in the video table(which also stores the image and video names), so I'm not understanding why I'm getting this error.
Below is the watchScreen.php,

```
$v_id = $_SESSION['v_id'];
$query=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT video_name FROM video WHERE v_id='$v_id'");
while($my_video=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
?>
<video width="60%" height="60%" style="background-color:#585858; border: 4px solid darkorange; border-radius:20px;" controls>
<source src="uploads/<?php echo $my_video['video_name']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<?php } ?>
```

below is where the image is clicked,

```
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] == true){
$query=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM video ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");
while($all_video=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
?>
<a href="watchScreen.php"><image src="thumbnails/<?php echo $all_video['image_name']; ?>" width="300" height="200"></a>
<?php } } ?>
```

below is the mySQL code,

```
CREATE TABLE video(
v_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
video_name VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
id INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY user_id(id)
REFERENCES users(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE,
n_views INT,
image_name VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL
);
```

The video and image names are added on a third page like so,

```
mysqli_query($link, INSERT INTO video(video_name, id, image_name) VALUES('$video_path', '$id', '$image_path'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the session for saving or passing data from one page to another. In your case you must pass the video ID as the parameter in the link ex.

```
<a href="watchScreen.php?video=1">video image </a>
```

Then on the watchScreen.php you should get the video id.

```
<?php

$v_id = $_GET['v_id'];
if(!is_numeric($v_id)){
   header("redirect: previouspage.php");
   exit();
}

// we validated, now we can do the query.

$query=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT video_name FROM video WHERE v_id='$v_id'");
while($my_video=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
?>
<video width="60%" height="60%" style="background-color:#585858; border: 4px solid darkorange; border-radius:20px;" controls>
<source src="uploads/<?php echo $my_video['video_name']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<?php } ?>

hope it helps.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same error after trying your code.

Comment: Can you update your code to see some of the table values and how you add the id to the link   ( "watchScreen.php?video=1 )

Answer (score 0):

Try removing quotes from around '$v_id';

Try:

```
"SELECT video_name FROM video WHERE v_id= $v_id";
```